# Expect: Can I set a permanent pattern - action pair for multiple expect command

Tags: tcl, expect

I work with an embedded system which I can access through a serial debug port for debugging. I want to use it's cli interface that can be accessed with `telnet localhost` in debug console (even before the system is fully up) through expect. The problem is, the cli interface kicks me out at random times with `Connection closed by foreign host.` near startup (this behavior cannot be changed in the system).

This is the background, my question is that is there any method or trick in expect with which I can set a pattern-action pair permanently for all expect command (in some specific scope)? I would like to setup something like this:

```
expect "Connection closed by foreign host." { error "cli closed" }
```

And use this in all the expect command in all my tcl `proc` that handles cli stuff, then I would call my `proc` with `catch` from the main program, and could handle the disconnection. If I can't set this pattern-action pair permanently, I have to include this in all my `expect` command, which would be really tedious (or use some kind of state instead of multiple expect command, which would be even more tedious..)

Any other idea to work around this is welcome too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an `expect_before` command: The patterns and actions defined in expect_before are "imported" into every subsequest `expect` command. So, you want:

```
expect_before "Connection closed by foreign host." { error "cli closed" }
```